# "<program> is not responding" while debugging in gnome 3 (ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: gnome, java, games, 17.10

Every time I'm debugging a Java game using graphics from OpenGL (libGDX framework), step by step (on my IDE), Gnome 3 freeze the game window and lock my mouse events outside that window, asking for a FORCE QUIT or WAIT because of a non responsive window (the game being debugged).

How can I ignore that message in the future (or delay it)? I can't debug anything with that open dialog, even if I press *Wait* (the dialog reappear again after 2 seconds or so)?

NOTE: CPU usage is a 1%.

Comment: `gnome-shell --version` ?

Comment: This file seems to be related: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/gnome-3-36/js/ui/closeDialog.js (note the version). In theory, you could engage in attempts at a dirty hack on this file (or another, nearby) to unblock your work temporarily, until you get a usable answer here. If you would want to try, this answer can put you on track with it: https://askubuntu.com/a/1317692/1157519

Comment: @Levente this "bug" was interrupting my work, 3 years ago. So one year of wating force me to move to KDE. I cannot test gnome-shell --version

Comment: Understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed.  A backport was released for Ubuntu 18 as gnome-shell 3.28.4 on 2019-6-6.   See [How To Disable the "Window not responding" Dialog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068921/how-to-disable-the-window-not-responding-dialog)

The underlying cause is the gnome API for interactive programs.  Once this API is activated, gnome expects the application to collect events and respond in a timely way, and the application sends a sort of heartbeat to prove it is responding.  When the application stops sending the heartbeat, gnome brings up this dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is if, when stepping through the code, you are getting to a point where the app is expecting some input from the user: a keyboard input, mouse movement etc. If the app is now locked waiting for that input it will be stuck there, but you are in the debugger, stepping to the next line of code. So your app never gets there because its waiting, and the debug can't move on because its waiting for the app to complete whats its doing.

Its called a deadly embrace

Comment: Yes, but this cannot be reproduced on other windows manager, like KDE, windows 7, windows 10, macOS. Already tested. It's a gnome problem

Answer (score -1):

Check your CPU or RAM usage. This might be a simple hardware bottleneck considering what’s happening. Most IDEs use up quite a lot of system resources,and I doubt yours is different. I found an [O’Reily](https://books.google.com/books?id=NxykJ3b-zqwC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=opengl%20is%20bloated&source=bl&ots=Kkp1v32l5g&sig=ACfU3U0TYkqGEpmdSu1As27ExEcFv3BEYA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjllrHnkMLnAhUUOs0KHRR9A4sQ6AEwD3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=opengl%20is%20bloated&f=false) book that states that over time the OpenGL API became more and more bloated on top of that. Try killing some tasks and look again. There might be some more information about disabling the repeated dialog boxes [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068921/how-to-disable-the-window-not-responding-dialog).

Comment: CPU and ram usage are ok. There's half physical ram available. Almost Zero CPU usage.

Comment: @francogp That’s pretty interesting. I’ll keep looking.