# False "application not responding" box is creating havoc with GDB

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm trying to debug a C++ application using GDB and the Qt Creator IDE. Every time the debugger stops on a breakpoint, Ubuntu (v 17.10) thinks the application is frozen and issues the dialog box with the warning that "{application} is not responding" with options to force quit or wait. Waiting only results in the same dialog popping up 5 seconds later. The debugger is unusable while the dialog box is open. Is there a way to disable this warning entirely in Ubuntu?

Note 1: just found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969237/program-is-not-responding-while-debugging-in-gnome-3-ubuntu-17-10) which is very similar but with Java.

Note 2: This happens in Gnome3 but not Unity. A temporary work-around is to log in using the Unity desktop.

Note 3: It appears this has been fixed in Ubuntu 18.04 (GCC 7.3).

Comment: That's going to be tricky I think - if I understand the issue correctly, it's because the debugger pauses the application's event loop, preventing it from responding to the window manager's [_NET_WM_PING](https://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472543696) signal.

Comment: I don't know if you can see the (deleted) answer to the similar question you linked, but the answerer did file a bug report [<something> is not respoding window is constantly showing when debugging a program in Eclipse](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1740869) (AFAIK the issue is the same regardless of either the debugger or application language) that you might want to add to ("affects me too")

Comment: Thanks for the link; I can't see the deleted answer. This issue must be tied to some specific configuration - I would think that not being able to use a debugger would cause an outrage if it affected everyone.

Answer (score 2):

There is a gnome shell extension to disable the force close dialog. It isn't the best solution but it helps working around apps that "lock" the GUI.

Download [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/uploads/12123026d72dee17d0c67ed287135a22/disable-force-quit_fmuellner.gnome.org.shell-extension.zip)

Extract it to  `$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/disable-force-quit@fmuellner.gnome.org/`

Reload Gnome with Alt+F2, r, enter (it won't kill your session / apps)

Open Tweaks, under Extensions, activate it.